# Power BI - show latest rows which meet criteria / sum to N

Tags: filter, powerbi, criteria

I'm trying to add a table which will show the most recent 10 orders by customer. I have a customer level filter, so if I choose a customer then the table shows only orders relating to them.

I've added in a visual filter, 'Top N', and selected to show the latest 10 by date. However if there were multiple orders on a given date (see pic) then it returns more than the 10 latest orders - it counts the 10 latest unique dates, allowing duplicates.

How do I redo this so that the total count of orders I get returned is 10, not the total count of unique dates? Also worth adding sometimes 'Order' returns a number greater than 1 for a given row, though in the example below they are all 1s.

'Orders' is a measure

Thanks for any help

[image: Pic]

Comment: Suppose you have 20 orders on one date. How do you tie break?

Comment: That's a good question, I'm not sure, I'd need to see how often that happened and think about it. Keen to have an answer to the main question first! I'd be happy to cut the data at the final order which tipped it over 10 I guess

Comment: The solution I had in mind was to create a ranking measure based on date and your tie-breaker criteria and use that measure as a filter instead of Latest Purchase Order Date. This might still work without a tiebreaker using [skip enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/rankx-function-dax).

Comment: @KieranIngram did you try Count(Distinct) for the Last Purchases Order?